# Attachments not related to email-to-case

Tags: attachment, apex-email-service, files, email2case

I use the email-to-case functionnality to create a case from an email.

I use an apex handle class to create the case and the email message.

It works good but I don't want the attachment in the case and in the email message.

In the setup, I enabled "Save Email-to-Case attachments as Salesforce Files" and "Show Email Attachments in Case Attachments Related List" but I can't see the attachment or the file in the case related list and the email message related list.

What is wrong in my setup?

Is it because I use an apex handle class?

How can I relate the attachment in the handle class?

Thanks

Comment: i'm confused -- On-demand email-to-case doesn't require any apex to get Cases created and it inherently supports email attachments

Comment: If I read the documentation (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customizesupport_email.htm&type=5), I need to develop a Salesforce Apex email services to turn emails into cases.

Comment: Email to Case, once you configure it for a given email address, say support@mycompany.com, will automatically create the case and add the attachments.  No apex code is required.  Apex inbound email services are for different use cases; eg creating a Lead from an email or taking a mail body keyword and updating a record.

Comment: But what if I need to send email from Salesforce and get responses from the cases?
All emails will be correctly related to the case automatically?

Comment: Read about threadIds and, if your org is brand new, the replacement for threadIds introduced in Winter21

Answer (score 1):

I added this code and it's working:

```
List<Attachment> attachments = new List<Attachment>();
        // Save attachments
        if(email.textAttachments != NULL && email.textAttachments.size() > 0){
            for (Messaging.Inboundemail.TextAttachment tAttachment : email.textAttachments) {
                attachments.add(new Attachment(
                    Name = tAttachment.fileName,
                    Body = Blob.valueOf(tAttachment.body),
                    ParentId = caseToUse.Id
                ));
            }
        }

        //Save any Binary Attachment
        if(email.binaryAttachments != NULL && email.binaryAttachments.size() > 0){
            for (Messaging.Inboundemail.BinaryAttachment bAttachment : email.binaryAttachments) {
                attachments.add(new Attachment(
                    Name = bAttachment.fileName,
                    Body = bAttachment.body,
                    ParentId = caseToUse.Id
                ));
            }
        }
```